# JSP displaying Datetime instead of Date

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a JSP that is fetching records from an Oracle database. When I preform the SQL query in Oracle, I am getting dates in the format that I expect (i.e. 06-JAN-14).

However, in my JSP, I am using JSTL to query the database and put the records into a JQuery DataTable. Unfortunately, somewhere along in the process, timestamps are being added to the dates, i.e. (2014-01-07 00:00:00.0).

This is my SQL query inside the JSP.

```
<sql:query var="retrieveMovers" dataSource="jdbc/blahApp">
    SELECT * FROM blah
</sql:query>
```

This is the table I am outputting results to.

```
    <table id="movers" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Security</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>Bid Price</th>
                <th>Bid Percent Change</th>
                <th>Security Description</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${retrieveMovers.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${row.security}</td>
                    <td>${row.comment}</td>
                    <td>${row.bid_price}</td>
                    <td>${row.bid_percent_change}</td>
                    <td>${row.security_description}</td>
                    <td>${row.date}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Can anyone make any suggestions how I can ensure my date row doesn't have a time stamp added to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Date doesn't have any intrinsic format. What you're seeing is the result of calling `toString()` on the `java.sql.Timestamp` instance of the row. You should format the date as you want it:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${row.date}" pattern="dd MMM yyyy" />
```

for example.

Comment: I embedded that in the <td> element and it worked great. I had seen that being used in other examples, but didn't realise the output was a string that I could insert directly into my <td> element.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```